# itext pdf reader is not reading special characters

Tags: itext

Special characters like ₱ ₩ ฿ ৳ ₹ are not being able to be read by itext pdf reader in proper format. Can they be read properly by itext pdf reader and if so how we can implement it?

Comment: you may post the code with the issue, so that others can help

Comment: And additionally please provide a sample PDF illustrating the issue. Oftentimes pdfs simply do not contain the information required for correct text extraction.

Comment: What @mkl says is correct. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxGEEv7ibHE) to find out the possible issues you can encounter. Moreover: text extraction is functionality that improved drastically in iText over the last couple of years. Which iText version are you using? Old versions extract much less text than newer versions.